# Given the characters in odd position and even position of a string, how can we combine them to get the final string in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know we can separate the odd and even characters from an array using:

```
evenstring = orignalstring[::2]
oddstring = originalstring[1::2]
```

What if I am just given 'evenstring' and 'oddstring'? How can I reverse it to get the original string in python?

Comment: Your code doesn't work (unless `orignalstring` and `originalstring` happen to have the same value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
originalstring = ''.join([''.join(x) for x in zip(evenstring, oddstring)])
```

If the length doesn't match you can do

```
if(len(oddstring) != len(evenstring)):
    originalstring = originalstring + evenstring[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know which one is the even and which one is the odd, the two strings will always be in one of two states:

- equal length - If the original string is even
- evenstring will be longer by 1 char - If the original string is odd

Then you can just:

```
result = []
for i in range(len(oddstring)):
    result.extend([evenstring[i], oddstring[i]])
if len(evenstring) > len(oddstring):
    result.append(evenstring[-1])
result_str = "".join(result)
```

You can also acheive a shorter solution using the `zip` function.
**Note that other answers here might not work with odd-length strings.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` and `zip`:

```
out1 = ''.join(''.join(f for f in tup) for tup in zip(oddstring, evenstring))
```

For example:

```
oddstring = "13579"
evenstring = "24680"

out1 = ''.join(''.join(f for f in tup) for tup in zip(oddstring, evenstring))

print(out1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
1234567890
```

Comment: The inner join is unnecssary if you're looping over the tuple: `''.join(f for tup in zip(evenstring, oddstring) for f in tup)`. Alternatively, you could just name `tup` in the inner join calls, without the generator expression that doesn't do anything. I've also reversed the even and odd inputs, you have them swapped (the first character is index zero, which is even).